# How to disable annoying MySql update console

Tags: mysql, windows

I have installed mysql 5.7, and from time to time (once per several days) it looks for updates (as I understand). Console window opens for several seconds, and then dissappear. It doesn't care, that I'm watching a movie in this time, and this console is on the top of my player. It's really annoying, why MySql is updating in this user unfriendly way? Can I configure it to do it silently?

Answer (score 12):

I may be running a more recent version of MySQL, but what I had to do to disable this was:

- Run the MySQL Installer (located at C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows)
- Click the wrench icon
- Un-check the box to check for updates

Comment: This was not enough for me. I also had to adjust it in Task Scheduler.

Comment: Yes, This does not do the trick. You have to do the Task scheduler thing as well. I just deleted the scheduled task altogether. Go to the Task Scheduler as described by @Ujjwal Singh And just delete the task. One important point is that it seems from the question that this issue exists on a personal computer, which justifies disabling auto-update. In a production environment, I'd suggest leaving it on in case any important security patches are published.

Answer (score 5):

This was answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638238/strange-mysql-popup-mysql-installer-is-running-community-mode

> Go to Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools and
> open Task Scheduler.
>
> In the Task Scheduler navigate to Task Scheduler Library > MySQL and
> select Installer.
>
> From the list at the center of the window right-click ManifestUpdate
> and select Disable

Comment: Thanks, your solution is useful, because I installed only MySQL Server and I can't change settings using Workbench or Notifier.

Answer (score 2):

In the System Tray - click on the Dolhin icon:

[image: Dolphin icon]

Actions -> Options -> Untick "Automatically check for updates every x weeks".

I'm giving this a +1 because I also found it annoying and your question prompted me to investigate.

Comment: In what application should I use these instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure MySQL Notifier is running.
Taskbar -> System Tray -> MySQL Notifier,
Select Actions -> Options
Uncheck the "Automatically check for updates every x weeks".

This may limit the security or functionality of your installation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best is to hide the console only, and let it do what it's meant to do in the background.

Go to 'Task scheduler' > expand 'Task scheduler library' > 'MySQL' > 'Installer' > 'Manifest Update' > right-click 'Properties' > choose 'Run whether user is logged on or not' > check 'Do not store password...'

That should do it.